# Ubuntu broadcasting UPnP messages

Tags: networking, upnp

I notice this with iftop:

```
   # Host name (port/service if enabled)            last 2s   last 10s   last 40s cumulative
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 192.168.0.1:41144                        =>        61B        61B        61B     2.86KB
     239.255.255.250:1900                     <=         0B         0B         0B         0B
```

where 192.168.0.1 is my server. Seems to me that my server is broadcasting UPnP messages. What process is doing this? How can I find it?

**Context**

My network setup is this:
Internet ... [eth0] my server (acting as a router) [eth1] ... [eth0Asus] Asus wireless router [eth1Asus] ... wireless LAN.
I'm testing using `iftop -i eth1`.

```
sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[1] 22                         LIMIT IN    Anywhere                  
[2] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[3] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere

uname -a
Linux gigi-desktop 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: What does `netstat -anp | grep 41144` show?

Comment: Well, I saw your suggestion after already finding the solution. It is a good one, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the guilty process; it’s Plex (despite having DLNA and GDM disabled). This is how I found:

```
sudo tcpdump -nn -vv -i eth0 'port 1900'
```

The output formatting of tcpdump is such that allowed me to notice the repetition of the source port used for broadcasting. Initially (using iftop) I thought it was a random port when if fact it wasn’t totally (it seems to be the same for the process lifetime).

```
sudo netstat -lpn | grep 62027
```

Using netstat I then was able to find the process using port 62027.